# Why it is said that the information of a black hole resides on the event horizon, while a singularity resides on the inside?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, information

Doesn't the statement that a black hole's information resides on the event horizon contradict the statement that there exist a singularity in the centre of the black hole?

Mass falling into the hole, according to an observer who's falling along with the mass sees the mass fall towards the singularity, so the information doesn't end up on the horizon.

If an observer looks at a freely falling mass towards the black hole from a great distance, the observer will also see the mass crossing the horizon falling towards the singularity. Only for clocks that stay at a fixed position with respect to the event horizon time advances slower. But a freely falling body, maximising it's falling time (though passing through points where time advances at a slower pace, or even at zero pace at the horizon, after which the radial space dimension swaps with the time dimension) is just seen as passing the horizon, so it's not frozen at the horizon. How else could black holes have developed?

Comment: So if it passes the horizon and gets inside, and later the black hole evaporates through Hawking radiation which has been proven has no information, after the evaporation where is that information? And do you know what information means in this context, just one example of a bit of information? If you do enough research to answer those questions I'm willing to try to answer your question, if not the question is too general. You need to ask some specific question on something you can specify in phyiaics. Vote to close as too general

Comment: A distant observer will never "see" the mass crossing the horizon. But as to whether the mass actually does cross, according to the distant observer that is, depends on the simultaneity convention.